# How to call ASP.NET MVC Web Api service from Windows Phone 8?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-phone-8, webclient

I'm trying to call the service which is uploaded to the cloud from Windows Phone 8 application. The problem is I'm always getting 404 response. It's funny but the service is successfully called from Windows 8 application I've built previously.
This is my code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompleted;
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://heronmobileapi.azurewebsites.net/api/events?parameter=showcase", UriKind.Absolute));

void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string result = e.Result; 
    }
```

I have also tried to use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse with no success. I also have issues calling this service on local machine, but now it's on the internet, and it should be called easily. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have just noticed that it cannot even call the Google.
Calling the http://www.google.com throws an exception.

Comment: This is the exception message I get: An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Well the problem is that Windows Phone emulator doesn't have internet access. You should enable it inside Hyper-V Manager. How you do that I don't know. What those people from Microsoft think? I am a developer and not virtual machine administrator. That is why they have so little quality applications in the store. Because they made development harder instead of easier.